# Pegar os registros repetidos de uma coluna a partir de outra coluna

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo

**Olá a todos!**
Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema: quero pegar a quantidade de valores que se repetem na coluna **tipo_doenca** a partir da coluna de **localidade**, ou seja, **pegar a quantidade de registros com a mesma doença de uma única localidade**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DESDE JÁ AGRADEÇO :D**

Comment: Não precisa colocar **resolvido** na pergunta. O fato de você aceitar minha resposta já é entendido como resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facinho amigo:

```
SELECT localidade, tipo_doenca as doenca, COUNT(tipo_doenca) as quantidade 
FROM pessoasDoentes GROUP BY localidade, tipo_doenca
```

**[Veja funcionando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99e59c/11)**

No php basta você fazer isso:

```
    $sql = "

    SELECT localidade, tipo_doenca as doenca, COUNT(tipo_doenca) as quantidade 
     FROM pessoasDoentes GROUP BY localidade, tipo_doenca

    ";

    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

    // imprimir os nossos resultados
    while($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $row->localidade.' = '.$row->doenca.' -> '.$row->quantidade;
    }
```

Se você tiver a localidade, você pode fazer isso:

```
    $localidade = "sao paulo";
    $sql = "

    SELECT tipo_doenca as doenca, COUNT(tipo_doenca) as quantidade 
     FROM pessoasDoentes WHERE localidade = '$localidade' GROUP BY  tipo_doenca

    ";
```

**[veja funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99e59c/12)**

*Obs.: Coloquei o nome da tabela como "pessoasDoentes", pois você não colocou na pergunta o nome original. Depois altere para o nome correto.*

Comment: Obrigado! Salvou minha vida e meu T.C.C.

Comment: @KingBrDZN que bom que pude ajudar! Boa sorte! =)